# Delaunay triangulation using opentk

Tags: opentk, delaunay

I am using openTK library to load xyz file in order to transform it to 3d meshes. When i use the tools of triangulation of this library i have an object where the triangles not connected.[image: Original point clouds][image: Result of triangulation].

i have used the code below:

```
        string fileNameLong = "bunny.xyz";
        vertices = IOUtils.ReadXYZFile_ToVertices(fileNameLong, false);
        Vertices.SetColorOfListTo(vertices, new Vector3d(1, 0, 0));
        Model3D myModel = new Model3D("bunny");
        myModel.VertexList = vertices;

        myModel.CalculateNormals_Triangulation();

        this.CreateLinesForNormals(myModel);


        ShowModel_WithLines(myModel, true);
        Model3D.Save_OBJ(myModel, path, "bunny_Triangulated.obj");
```

Comment: there are any c# library that make triangulation other openTK?